# java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#11, cac

My goal is to read information from a CAC card and use `pkcs11` to extract information from it and sign my document. I couldn't find the right dll for my hardware, so I installed `openSC` on my machine and used `opensc-pkcs11.dll` in the following code:

```
String configName = "pkcs.cnf"; //my config file that points to opensc-pkcs11.dll
String PIN = "123456";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
Security.addProvider(p);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
char[] pin = PIN.toCharArray();
keyStore.load(null, pin);
```

But I'm getting an error at the following location

```
 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
```

with the Error stacktrace:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-FooAccelerator
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Help!

Comment: I believe the problem is with your .dll, check if it the correct dll file you are referrring

Comment: Why dont you use KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",p); to get the keystore, might help you in getting close to your issue

Comment: @mhasan, that did not work either. Can I download the dll from the internet? I am using a CAC card

Answer (score 2):

First create a `config.cfg` as shown below:

```
name=name of your CAC card
slot=1
library=C:\Windows\System32\eps2003csp11.dll 
\\This is the dll file for etoken like this when you are installing driver, a separate dll file would be generated for your CAC card.
```

Then provide the config file path in the program, as shown below:

```
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configFilepath);
Security.addProvider(p);
```

Comment: I noticed a recent edit to this post, which dramatically change your intention, Please check if it's your intention or not

Comment: `slot` instead of the documented `slotListindex` fixed it for me, worth mentioning